# What is the best partitioning strategy for multiple distinct count measures in a cube

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap-cube

I have a cube that has a fact table with a month's worth of data. The fact table is 1.5 billion rows.
Fact table contains the following columns { **DateKey,UserKey,ActionKey, ClientKey, ActionCount** } .
The fact table contains one row per user per client per action per day with the no of activities done.

Now I want to calculate the below measures in my cube as follows

**Avg Days Engaged per user**
AVG([Users].[User Key].[User Key], [Measures].[DATE COUNT])

**Users Engaged >= 14 Days**
SUM([Users].[User Key].[User Key], IIF([Measures].[DATE COUNT] >= 14, 1, 0))

**Avg Requests Per User**
IIF([Measures].[USER COUNT] = 0, 0 ,[Measures].[ACTIVITY COUNT]/[Measures].[USER COUNT])

So to do this, I have created two distinct count measures DATE COUNT and USER COUNT which are distinct aggregations on the DateKey and UserKey columns of fact table. I want to know partition the measure group(s) ( there are 3 of them bcoz of distinct measure going in it's own measure group).

What is the best strategy to partition the cube? I have read the [analysis service distinct count](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCwQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fdownload%2Fdetails.aspx%3Fid%3D891&ei=3elXVIPmKIj2igK23oG4AQ&usg=AFQjCNGIkZHTa1bWLRDne8tPdHVMWuk0SA&sig2=0XOK82PiirzyRMpym1ruGg&bvm=bv.78677474,d.cGE) guide end-end and it mentioned that partitioning the cube by non-overlapping user ids is the best strategy for single user queries and user X time is the best for single user time-set queries.

I want to know if I should partition by cube into 75 partitions each (1.5 billion rows/20 million rows per partition) which will have  each partition with non-overlapping and sequential user ids or should I partition it into 31 partitions one per day with overlapping userid but distinct days in each partition or 31 * 3 = 93 partitions where I break down the cube into per day and then for each day further partition in to 3 equal parts with non-overlapping user ids within each day (but users will overlap between days) or partition by ActionKey into 45 partitions of un-equal size since most of the times the measures are sliced by Action?

I'm a bit confused because the paper only talks about optimizing on a single distinct count measure, where as I need to do distinct counts on both user and dates for my measures.

any tips ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first take a step back and try the Many-to-Many dimension count technique to achieve Distinct Count results without the overhead of actual Distinct Count aggregations.

Probably the best explanation of this is the "Distinct Count" section of the "Many to Many Revolution 2.0" paper:

http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/

Note Solution C is the one I am referring to.

You usually find this solution scales much better than a standard "Distinct Count" measure.  For example I have one cube with 2b rows in the biggest Fact (and only 4 partitions), and a "M2M Distinct Count" fact on 9m rows - performance is great e.g. 6-7 hours to completely reprocess all the data, less than 5 seconds for most queries.  The server is OK but not great e.g. VM, 4 cores, 32 GB RAM (shared with SQL, SSRS, SSIS etc), no SSD.

I think you can get carried away with too many partitions and overcomplicating the design.  The basic engine can do wonders with careful design.

Comment: I tried the distinct count using M2M technique first and it didn't scale well at all. My queries are actually timing out :(

Comment: I tried the distinct count using M2M technique first and it didn't scale well at all. My queries are actually timing out :(. I have a pretty good machine too. 16 cores 48GB RAM and 1TB SSD hard disk. I'm curious when you mentioned that you only have 4 partitions in your 2 billion rows table without any aggregations. Is that true? My cube processing with nearly 1000 partitions across 3 measure groups takes 4-5 hours but queries are taking > 15 mins from cold start. Are aggregations really that bad? I have set full aggregations for all partitions on the DimAction.ActionName dimension

Comment: I do have aggregations and they seem essential to query performance. I just ran the wizard (aiming for 10-20% performance boost, stopping if it goes over 100 Aggregations), and the results seem fine - it came up with 74 aggregations for that MG.  All 4 partitions use the same Agg design. It's been running for over a year now.  I suspect you have overcooked both the partition and aggregation designs.

Comment: How many distinct measures do you have? And how many partitions in each measure group? I roughly have 300 partitions across my fact measure group and 4 portions on my 33 million dimension..I have distinct count of date and users and both have m2m relationship via fact measure group

Comment: There are no distinct count measures.  Instead you add a count measure based on the dimension data.  There are 4 partitions on the MG and no partitions on the dimension.

Comment: I meant how many dimensions and measure groups do you have in your cube that have many2many relationship with the fact table as intermediate measure group ? I have 4 dimension and 2 measure groups that are related as many romana with fact measure group as intermediate and so total 8 many2many dimension relationships with 1.5 billion row intermediate measure  group

Comment: I have 1 dimensions and 3 MGs using the M2M relationship.